# AudioObjectAddPropertyListener for framebuffersize change Core Audio

Tags: macos, core-audio

I need to create a AudioObjectAddPropertyListener for when buffersize is changed.
How to do that?
I have one for samplerate:

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress paSamplerate;
paSamplerate.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate;
paSamplerate.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
paSamplerate.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;

AudioObjectAddPropertyListener(id,&paSamplerate,listener_proc,NULL);
```

I have tried with the selector kAudioDevicePropertyLatency but I'm not getting the callback

Comment: What about listening for `kAudioDevicePropertyBufferFrameSize` changes?

Comment: `AudioObjectPropertyAddress pa;`
`pa.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyBufferFrameSize;`
`pa.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;`
`pa.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;`
            
 `AudioObjectAddPropertyListener(id,&pa,listener_proc,NULL);`

I'm not getting the callback from this...